# Return non duplicate values after successful query in temporal table and AVERAGE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server and I have a successful query that is calculating 'MinutesOut' in my very large temporal data set. Due to the number of records, I want to start eliminating useless rows as well as summarize to the day.

The successful query:

```
select 
    t.*,
    case 
       when CustomersOut > 0
          then datediff(minute, RecordedDateTime, 
                        lead(RecordedDateTime) over (partition by UtilityName, StateName, CountyName, CityName 
                                                     order by RecordedDateTime)) 
    end MinutesOut
from
    MyTable1 t
```

1. I want to eliminate all rows where 'MinutesOut' is NULL
2. Anytime the distinct records 'UtilityName', 'StateName, 'CityName', 'FullFIPSid', 'RecordedDateTime' is duplicated all records can be removed.
3. Lastly, is it possible to summarize the DATETIME column to the day instead of 1000x per day? That would be to calculate average 'MinutesOut' per each distinct 'UtilityName'+ 'StateName' + 'CityName'+ 'FullFIPSid'+ 'RecordedDateTime'

Comment: *Microsoft SQL* - do you mean Microsoft **Access** with SQL (add a `ms-access` tag), or do you mean Microsoft **SQL Server** (add `sql-server`) ?? Please be **precise** !

Comment: I apologize. New here, getting the hang of the format. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If your table has an ID to join on you could do something like this to remove the NULL MinutesOut

```
SELECT 
  t0.*,
  MinutesOut
FROM
MyTable1 t0 INNER JOIN ( SELECT CASE  WHEN CustomersOut > 0
      THEN datediff(minute, RecordedDateTime, lead(RecordedDateTime) over (partition 
by UtilityName, StateName,  CountyName, CityName 
  order by RecordedDateTime)) 
END MinutesOut from MyTable1) t1 ON t0.ID = t1.ID WHERE MinutesOut IS NOT NULL
```